# Validate cdi injection points

Tags: java, validation, cdi

I want something like this:

```
@Inject
@Validate //some my custom annotation
private SomeMyBean bean;
```

To call hibernate validator on injected bean on every injection and save validation result somewhere, e.g. in some other bean.

This should work just like Spring @Valid annotation, but use CDI and beans validation.

Could someone give me some clue how to achieve this aim?